# How do I customize my town's layout?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Is there any mod, cheat, or glitch to create your town map in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*? I'm very picky about my town map, but it seems I can never find the perfect one. So I wanted to know: Is there some way you can customize your town's layout? (Choose where the river flows or where the town hall is located, etc.) I have seen people say they did something to do so, but I could never figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately. 3DS games are unable to be modded yet unless the game has this feature in it. It may come out as a feature once an emulator and a emulation comes out but until then, no.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible with a modded 3DS and a New Leaf save editor. Using a save editor, you can do other stuff like changing your villagers or other things. It may be too late to mod a clean 3DS now, as Nintendo updated the 3DS to the point where homebrew is impossible (at the time).

TLDR: Use a save editor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but its tiring. Make your first character and when Rover gets to the maps look at the ones he shows. If you don't like them exit the game without saving and do it again. Still all maps are very similar but if you want a perfect map this is a good tactic. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

If you reset your town and go back to the beginning of the game, Rover lets you pick your town map. So yes, you can pick where stuff is.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question - he's asking for the ability to craft the town's layout manually, instead of relying on the game's random number generator to come up with one that is satisfactory